# SQLite truncates my data

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have data that looks like this in console:

```
"to add: 
rand_num = 1-231881-6-70885-12
name = heat boy
type = caucasian
price = 700.0
date = 2018-08-01"
```

Instead I get this for some reason in database:

```
"to add: 
rand_num = 1-231881-6-70885-12
name = heat boy
type = caucasian
price = 70"
```

My controller:

```
public class Controller {
    private description =   "to add: \n"+
                            "rand_num = 1-231881-6-70885-12 \n"+
                            "name = heat boy \n"+
                            "type = caucasian \n"+
                            "price = 700.0 \n"+
                            "date = 2018-08-01"


    private Model textFields() {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setRand_num(description.getText());
    }
    try {
        DAOClass daoClass = new DAOCLass();
        daoClass.insert(textFields());
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

My model:

```
public class model {
    private SimpleStringProperty description;


    public Model() {
        this("");
    }    


    public model(String description) {
        super();
        this.rand_num = new SimpleStringProperty(description);
    }

    //getter
        public String getDescription() {
            return description.get();
        }
    //setter
       public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description.set(description);
        }   
    //property
    public StringProperty descriptionProperty(){
        return description;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "to add: " + 
    }
}
```

DAO class

```
public class DAO {
    public void insert(Model model) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //initializing PreparedStatement
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String updateQuery =
                        "INSERT INTO modelDB \n" +
                        "(description) \n" +
                        "VALUES \n" +
                        "(?)";

        //Execute DELETE operation
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, model.description());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("Error: " + e);
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if(preparedStatement != null)
            {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

My SQLite table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE userActivityLogs (
    logId           INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    description        VARCHAR (10000)
);
```

Now I know there is no limit for SQLite and even if there was I am using varChar(10000). It all displays perfectly on console but once it is in the database it is truncated. Why is that and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you saving the data?

Comment: what tool are you using to query sqlite databse

Comment: I use this process to save data  controller -> model-> DAO-> database
I use sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1 as a library for java.

Comment: Can you add the piece where you save the data? If possible including the model

Comment: Varchar(10000)? I assume you are serializing the data and persisting it in a text field? Could you upload your code so we can help you?

Comment: @Stefan Sorry it took so long to reply. I included the controller, model and DAO classes for further reference.

Comment: @Sergio Daniel Coronel Malvarez : Hi there, yes, I included my other classes.

Comment: My suggestion is to refactor your class names properly. Your controller class is `Model` right? and your model class name is `model` ???

Comment: @Stefan, I changed the code. I think it is clearer now to understand the problem. Basically the string gets cut when pasted to database.

Comment: @Blasanka I changed the example so its easier to understand. Basically, the model is not the problem. Its the string getting passed to database. It is incomplete once it gets to database. I believe there is a limit somewhere. How can I lift the sql limit for the maximum length so I can pass the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

I dont´t see your random number truncated so the varchar(10000) isn´t at play here.

What i see in your code is:

```
preparedStatement.setString(4, model.getPrice());
preparedStatement.setString(4, model.getDate());
```

You are using the same index for Price and Date.

Comment: Hi Sergio, that was my mistake but that is not the problem. I refactored the code so its easier to understand. Basically I am passing a string to SQLite through controller class which gets cut but in console it displays the whole string.

Comment: Without debugging i´m not seeing any simple error, theoretically there isn´t a limit for the TEXT types except the global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH.

Comment: Are you sure that the "setString(1, model.description());" contains the whole text?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it cointains the whole text. Do I have to set something for SQLite so it will accept a larger length? I remembe I had to set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` in order to use foreign keys. Do I have to do something similar in SQLite to make it accept a larger string?

Comment: From documentation: The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion. The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647.